# post_status => publish not working

Tags: query-posts, wp-insert-post, save-post, publish, wp-update-post

I have a front end form that let users submit a post.

This is how i store the data when a post is submitted :

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] )) {
        $post_information = array(
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
        'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
$new_post = wp_insert_post( $post_information );
```

The post is not showing in my post page unless i go through my dashboard and click over The UPDATE button.

THIS IS HOW I QUERY MY POSTS :

```
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page' => 5,
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_query' => array(
array( 'key' => '_wti_like_count','value' => 5, 'compare' => '<=','type' => 'numeric')
)
);

query_posts( $args );
```

How can i make my submitted posts publish automatically?

Comment: The above code works for me. Do you have any kind of approval system for the posts? In case the post's status is `draft` or `pending review`, you should see `PUBLISH` button. Since you see `UPDATE` button, the post must have been published.

Comment: Are you sure when you save the post from frontend, the post has meta data `_wti_like_count`? If it does not have, then it will never show up that post. Try the above `$args` without the `meta_query` and see whether it shows up the post or not.

Comment: i did it without the meta_query and they show up! how do i add the meta data _wti_like_count

Comment: because i want to organize them according to the number of the value of _wti_like_count <= 5

Comment: That's fine. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post gets added and published but since you have the meta query and the meta key is not added when you submit the post from frontend, it does not show up. Use the following code which adds the meta data as needed.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {
     $post_information = array(
                              'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
                              'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
                              'post_type' => 'post',
                              'post_status' => 'publish'
                         );

     $new_post = wp_insert_post( $post_information );

     // Add the post meta
     add_post_meta( $new_post, '_wti_like_count', 0, true );
     add_post_meta( $new_post, '_wti_unlike_count', 0, true );
     add_post_meta( $new_post, '_wti_total_count', 0, true );
}
```

Comment: Another little thing my friend! if i add a value like this add_post_meta( $new_post, '_wti_like_count', 1, true ); why the value 1 doesn't display on the front end ? It only shows 0

Comment: The data you see on the frontend is pulled from the plugin table `wti_like_post`. The meta data is just added to the post so that it can be used in custom queries like the one you have above. To keep things clean, always 0 is added to the post when created. As user keeps on voting for that post, both the values ( in the plugin table and meta data ) gets updated accordingly.

Comment: Alright my friend! Thank you so much! You are a life saver :D

Comment: Note that you can now do this within the wp_insert_post using the 'meta_input' attribute (e.g. `meta_input => array('meta_field_name => 'meta field value')`)

Comment: Hi all, Can you guys help me to solve the same issue? I am unable to solve the issue by going this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think that is because of you didn't added the author into the `$post_information` :

```
if( isset($_POST['submitted']) ):
    global $user_ID;
    $post_information = array(             
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
        'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'post_author' => $user_ID, 
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);
    if (!$post_id) {
        wp_die('Error');
    }
endif;
```

Comment: post_author is not the required one, it will still create the post :)

Comment: Yeah, i think is the way i query the my posts

Comment: @SabitaSahoo thanks to make me correct :) but the OP has not cleared his question as you can see that he updated his question.